# open markdown files in vim: only a few lines shown

Tags: vim, markdown

I'm facing the problem while displaying the markdown file content.

When i opens the .md file in vim , it just displays few lines

and there is s bottom bar which display line info,rest of the lines of the files are not visible.

[image]

I have this in .vimrc

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.md set filetype=markdown
```

Any idea what is the problem here ?

Comment: That line doesn't make any difference to my `vim` behaviour. Do you have any plugins installed which might be related?

Comment: i have other plugin installed , not any related to markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the file is [folded](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding); in that case moving on the line 2 and pressing `za` (or `zA` for recursively opening folds) should work.

If this is the case, there are tips [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/All_folds_open_when_opening_a_file) to set-up vim in order to decide how to fold files.